# Apache virtual host

Tags: apache2

Hi does this virtual host configuration is ok?. I,m trying to test it in my local machine and it don,t show the page. I disable the firewall to have all the ports open, do i have to do anything more to open the ports? or the virtual host configuration is wrong.

`<VirtualHost linux1:8890>`

`#General setup for the virtual host`
    `DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs/webpage1"`
    `ServerName linux1:8890`
`</virtualHost>`

Comment: i,m typing this url
http://linux1:8090

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add `Listen 8890` anywhere? Apache needs this command in order to listen to that port.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `Listen 8890` somewhere, also above the declaration of the Virtualhosts you need `NameVirtualHost *:8890`

The virtualhost you define is ok, but you can only access that virtualhost by the hostname.